# Use MySQL to determine whether today is a user's birthday

Tags: mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have all users' birthdays stored as a UNIXtimestamp and am wanting to send out e-mails each day to users that have a birthday that day.

I need to make a MySQL query that will get all of the rows that contain a birthday on today's date.

It seems like this should be fairly simple, but maybe I am just overcomplicating it.

Comment: As a side note: `birthdays stored as a unix timestamp`: You should think about changing this to using DATETIME. Timestamp can only store dates from 1970-01-01 to something around 2038. Once the first user enters a birthdate prior 1970, you will get errors. Check with the documentation on mysql!

Comment: Can you assume all your users are in roughly the same timezone?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should work:

```
   SELECT * 
      FROM USERS
      WHERE 
         DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account february 29, when there aren't leap years. The user has to send out emails on 28th february. You have to include 29th feb (if there isn't that day) into 28th feb.

Comment: February 29th birthday kids are already used to celebrate their birthday only once every 4 years.  
They get the no-birthday-spam privilege. Fair deal, isn't it?

Comment: Let's take this serious, whould you miss a Wireless Carrier bonus for your birthday 3 years in row?

Comment: I can use PHP to alter the mysql query if they have a feb 20 birthday.

Comment: bad approach, see my answer below

Answer (score 13):

Here is an answer that property takes into account leap-years and will always give you the users whose birthday is on the 29th of February at the same time as those on the 1st of March.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM USERS
  WHERE 
     DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')
     OR (
            (
                DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y') % 4 <> 0
                OR (
                        DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y') % 100 = 0
                        AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y') % 400 <> 0
                    )
            )
            AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d') = '03-01'
            AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') = '02-29'
        )
```

Comment: It works fine if you remove `FROM_UNIXTIME `.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the query below if date of birth stored in a table.

Today Birthday :

```
select * from TABLENAME
 where DAY(FIELDNAME) = DAY(CURDATE())
   and MONTH(FIELDNAME) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

Yesterday Birthday:

```
select * from TABLENAME
 where DAY(FIELDNAME) = DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
   and MONTH(FIELDNAME) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

Tomorrow Birthday:

```
select * from TABLENAME
 where DAY(FIELDNAME) = DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
   and MONTH(FIELDNAME) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

Comment: Note that the yesterday/tomorrow checks will fail for dates on the first or last day of a month -- should avoid resolving to the day/month until after comparing raw date distances.

Answer (score 4):

Since this gets more and more to be a code-golf question, here's my approach on solving this including taking care of the leap years:

```
select * 
from user
where (date_format(from_unixtime(birthday),"%m-%d") = date_format(now(),"%m-%d"))
   or (date_format(from_unixtime(birthday),"%m-%d") = '02-29'
       and date_format('%m') = '02' 
       and last_day(now()) = date(now())
      );
```

Explanation: The first where clause checks if somebody's birthday is today.
The second makes sure to only select those whose birthday is on Feb 29th only if the current day equals the last day of February.

Examples:

```
SELECT last_day('2009-02-01'); -- gives '2009-02-28'
SELECT last_day('2000-02-01'); -- gives '2009-02-29'
SELECT last_day('2100-02-01'); -- gives '2100-02-28'
```

Comment: This is my favourite as it is readable and doesn't use too many functions. I would however be tempted to check that the current date is the last day of feb (not row dependent) before checking that the user was born on the feb 29th (row dependent) on the off chance that the engine can use this and hasn't figured it out already.

Answer (score 4):

This should cover the leap year cases, and uses the internal date mechanics.

Basically it works by adding the years between the two dates to the date of birth and checks for equality with the current date:

```
WHERE dob + INTERVAL (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(dob)) YEAR = CURDATE();
```

Testing:

```
SELECT '2012-02-29' 
       + INTERVAL (YEAR('2015-02-28') - YEAR('2012-02-29')) YEAR 
       = '2015-02-28'; /* 1, is birthday */

SELECT '2012-02-28' 
       + INTERVAL (YEAR('2015-02-28') - YEAR('2012-02-28')) YEAR  
       = '2015-02-28'; /* 1, is birthday */

SELECT '2012-02-28'
       + INTERVAL (YEAR('2016-02-29') - YEAR('2012-02-28')) YEAR 
       = '2016-02-29'; /* 0, is NOT birthday  */

SELECT '2012-02-29'
       + INTERVAL (YEAR('2016-02-29') - YEAR('2012-02-29')) YEAR 
       = '2016-02-29'; /* 1, is birthday */
```

Answer (score 2):

I come across with this problem, and I just used this simple code using the `NOW();`

```
$myquery = "SELECT username FROM $tblusers WHERE NOW() = bd";
```

The results are today's birthdays so after that I working in sending emails to my users on their birthday.

I store my users bithdays using just the DATE so I always have `yy:mm:dd`, so this works like a charm, at least to me, using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer below doesn't actually work. It doesn't take into account the fact that a year is 365.24 (leap days now and then) days long, so the actual comparison against the users birthdate is complicated to say the least. I'm leaving it for historical reasons.**

> The other answers should work but if you want a slight optimization, say if there are many *many* rows, you are probably better off expressing the query directly in timestamp seconds. You can use the relations (slightly involved because of taking timezone into account):
>
> ```
> today_starts = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DATE(NOW()), NOW())
> today_ends = today_starts + 86400
> ```
>
> and then select records where the timestamp is between those values.

Comment: This doesn't take into account february 29, when there aren't leap years. The user has to send out emails on 28th february. You have to include 29th feb (if there isn't that day) into 28th feb.

Comment: @Pentium Actually, the more I think about it, the buggier this is. I'll edit and leave it as a warning against this kind of optimization. :)

Comment: this reminds me of a quote I once heard: "It could be that the purpose of your life is only to serve as a warning to other". Kudos to you for standing to your answer! (btw: http://www.despair.com/mis24x30prin.html )

Answer (score 1):

I took Saggi Malachi's answer and extended to include a birthday on 29th February into 28th February date, if in that year there is no such day.

```
SELECT * 
      FROM USERS
      WHERE 
         DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')
UNION
SELECT * 
      FROM USERS
      WHERE 
         DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y')%4 != 0 AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')='02-28' and DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') = '02-29'
```

Comment: This doesn't properly check for leap years. A leap year occurs every 4 years unless the year is divisible by 100 and not by 400. `isLeap = (year % 4) == 0 && !((year % 100) == 0 && (year % 400) != 0)

Comment: technically that is not how you detect a leap year (1900, 2100) are not leap years.

Comment: Actually, if you need to be serious about this, you have to take into account, that every 100 years, there's no leap year, but every 400 there is ... You wouldn't wanna send the leap-day-birthday kids two mails on Feb 28th and Feb 29th 2100 :-)

Comment: I am very much against adding any database overhead for such cases, this should be handled in your code and only run once a year. Databases are a very expensive resource, respect it. Also, why using UNION and not an OR?

Comment: "Databases are a very expensive resource"? On the contrary; perform your data manipulation as early as you can to save resources.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my contribution

```
SELECT
  DAYOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-(dayofyear(date_format(CURRENT_DATE,'%Y-03-01'))-60)=
  DAYOFYEAR(the_birthday)-(dayofyear(date_format(the_birthday,'%Y-03-01'))-60)
FROM
   the_table
```

The bits '(dayofyear(date_format(current_date,'%Y-03-01'))-60)' returns 1 on leap years since march 1st will be dayofyear number 61, and 0 on normal years.

From here it's just a matter of substracting that extra day to the "is-it-my-birthday"-calculation.

Comment: On the 1st of Jan for a `current_date` of a leap year and the 1st of Jan for a `the_birthday` of a non leap year you get `0 = 1`..

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy :)

```
select p.birthday, 
CASE YEAR(p.birthday)%4 + MONTH(p.birthday)-2 + dayofmonth(p.birthday)-29 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isBirthday29Feb,
CASE YEAR(now())%4  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isThisYearLeap,
IF(YEAR(p.birthday)%4 + MONTH(p.birthday)-2 + dayofmonth(p.birthday)-29=0 AND YEAR(now())%4 != 0,
            DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(p.birthday, INTERVAL 1  DAY), INTERVAL YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(p.birthday)  YEAR) ,
            DATE_ADD(p.birthday, INTERVAL YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(p.birthday)  YEAR)  
)as thisYearBirthDay
from person p;
```

This gives you a person's birthday calculated according the current year.
Then you can use it for other calculations!
The columns `isBirthday28Feb` and `isThisYearLeap` are given just to illustrate the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I took Saggi's answer and thought about modifying it so that it would show birthdays for next 7 days and noticed it also neatly solves the leap year problem :)

```
SELECT * 
   FROM USERS
   WHERE 
      DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d') AND
      DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m-%d')
```

Note it doesn't include the upper bound. For leap years nothing falls between '02-28' and '02-29', but for non-leap years the '02-29' falls between '02-28' and '03-01'.

---

If you'd want the next 7 days, use:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM USERS
   WHERE 
      DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthDate),'%m-%d') BETWEEN
      DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW()+INTERVAL 7 DAY,'%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE
DATE_FORMAT((birthDate),'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @now=now();
select * from user where (month(birthday) = month(@now) and day(birthday) = day(@now)) or
  (month(birthday) = 2 and day(birthday) = 29 and month(@now) = 2 and day(@now) = 28 and
  month(date_add(@now, interval 1 day)) = 3);
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account february 29, when there aren't leap years. The user has to send out emails on 28th february. You have to include 29th feb (if there isn't that day) into 28th feb.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just select all rows that matched the current day's date? You could also use the FROM_UNIXTIME() function to convert from unix timestamp to Date:

mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219);
        -> '2007-11-30 10:30:19'

This is documented from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 0):

Simple way

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MONTH(brith_day_table) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(birth_day_table) = DAY(NOW())
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing currently is determine if today is users birthday using sql and if yes send the wish separately, there is better approach to handling this.

1. Extract the wish details in excel
2. let [Wishing Application](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app) take care of the rest

At minimal it just need two things **excel file** with wish details (Date, name, email) and a configuration file (**application.properties**) and that is it, you are good to go.

Further there various [options to run](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Running) the application locally (Command line, foreground, background, docker, windows scheduler, unix cron etc) Cloud.

Application is [highly configurable](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Configurations-unleashed) , you can configure various details like:

- Workbook loading options
- Image options to send with wishes.
- SMTP Configurations
- Other application level configurations like, when to send wish, belated wish, logging etc.

  Disclaimer : I am the owner of the application

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.