# sql query selecting birthday today from number format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let say i have identification card number in this format

```
 720901155172
```

we can convert the number to birthday by using this code

```
        $data = '720901155172';
        $head = substr($data, 0, 6);

        $year = (int) substr($head, 0, 2);
        $currentYear = date('Y');

        $max = (int) substr($currentYear, 2, 4);

        $byear = $year + ($year > $max ? 1900 : 2000);
        $bmth = (int) substr($head, 2, 2);
        $bday = (int) substr($head, 4, 2);

        $bdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(sprintf('%s-%s-%s', $byear, $bmth, $bday)));
        echo $bdate;//output : 1972-09-01
```

how do i select all user that is having birthday today ?
is this possible ?

```
$sql="SELECT ic FROM users";
```

Comment: How does your table schema look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of :- [Use MySQL to determine whether today is a user's birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218378/use-mysql-to-determine-whether-today-is-a-users-birthday)

Comment: simple table uid mediumint(8) 
ic     varchar (25)
name varchar (128)

Comment: my number is not in unixtime

Comment: What is the date format, is it number of seconds from some year?

Comment: it is a unique identification card number

Comment: When you say `how do i select all user that is having birthday today` the "today" refers to the current timestamp ? or is it the derived timestamp i.e `1972-09-01` And what is the Birthday Column Name?

Comment: the derived date from ic column

Comment: It's just a where caluse .. am I missing someting `$sql="SELECT name FROM users where ic=derived_date"

Comment: need to convert ic first ..ic is in 720901155172 format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is first 6 digits of your ic is YYMMDD. If this is not the case please ignore.
Accordingly you need this conversion in sql.

```
    select ic,
    case when substring(ic,1,2) <Substring(YEAR(NOW()),-2) 
    then Concat('20',substring(ic,1,2),'-'  ,substring(ic,3,2),'-', substring(ic,5,2))
    else
     Concat('19',substring(ic,1,2),'-'  ,substring(ic,3,2),'-', substring(ic,5,2))
    end as derived_date
    from Users
```

please update 'Substring(YEAR(NOW()),-2)' with your $max, 2 digit year.

Answer (score 0):

Since the birthday that you need to look at is on positions 2-5 in the `ic` string you can use `REGEX` to match it with today's date.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ic REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}0901[0-9]{6}$';
```

Assuming each `ic` is a fixed length of 12 numbers this will match a string that:

1. starts with 2 numbers between 0-9
2. matches input date exactly
3. ends with 6 numbers between 0-9

Today's date part of the `REGEX` you will have to insert into the query dynamically with PHP, so the code would look (depending on what framework you are using) something like:

```
$db->get_results("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ic REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}%d[0-9]{6}$'", $date);
```