# How to get birthdate in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, date

I want to show the value of first_name and birth_date
of customers who were birthday today. What kind of queries should I do?

```
  $birthday = DB::table('customers')
  ->select(DB::raw('customers.first_name','customers.birth_date'))
  ->whereRaw('DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(birth_date) AND DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) + 0 >=  dayofyear(birth_date)')
  ->orderByRaw('DAYOFYEAR(birth_date)')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 $birthday = DB::table('customers')
  ->select(DB::raw('customers.first_name','customers.birth_date'))
  ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birth_date),'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')")
  ->orderByRaw('DAYOFYEAR(birth_date)')
  ->get();
```

Reference:
[Use MySQL to determine whether today is a user's birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218378/use-mysql-to-determine-whether-today-is-a-users-birthday)

Comment: I can query in databsae, but cannot query on php.

Comment: why do you want to use php for fetching today's birthdays?

Comment: I want to display the birthday value of my customers in my admin console to let staff know.

Comment: This query will returns all the customers having b'dy today. You can easily show those customers using $birthday->birth_date

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results by using the following query...

```
$today = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString();

$birthday = DB::table('customers')
    ->select('customers.first_name','customers.birth_date')
    ->whereDate('birth_date', $today)
    ->get();
```